# unable to fetch record based on a specific key in dynamo db and python

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, amazon-dynamodb

I have a child class where I am trying to fetch the dynamo db data based on a specific key, I tried multiple variations of passing a value to the key but somehow I am getting an error on the response.

```
class AdGroupDetailsRepository(Repository):
    def __init__(self, client, table_name):
        super().__init__(client)
        self.table_name = table_name

    def _exec_find_by_id(self, id: str):
        logger = get_provisioner_logger()
        logger.info("Table name is %s" % self.table_name)
        dynamo_table = self.client.Table(self.table_name)
        logger.info("Connected to the dynamo table...")
        logger.info("id is %s" % id)
        item = dynamo_table.get_item(Key={'ad_group': "bigdata"})
        logger.info("fetched account: ", item['Items'])
        return AdGroupDetails(id, item['account'], item['role'])
```

**Error**:

[image]

I am just trying to fetch the results which is nothing but the dictionary in dynamo's case and out of that I need to fetch the specific column values.

Dynamo table schema: `ad_group, account, role`

I am using the `dynamo resource` to connect to the dynamo table. Also, I am running it via lambda functions for the APIs.

Comment: If you read the docs: "If there is no matching item, GetItem does not return any data and there will be no Item element in the response." So, it's called "Item", not "Items". It's singular. And it will be absent if the item was not found.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A `get_item` does not have a key of `Items`:

`logger.info("fetched account: ", item['Items'])`

I believe your code is failing on this line, causing the exception to be returned.

```
    item = dynamo_table.get_item(Key={'ad_group': "bigdata"})['Item']
    logger.info("fetched account: " item)
    return AdGroupDetails(id, item['account'], item['role'])
```

Try CLI:

```
aws dynamodb get-item \
--table-name <Your Table Name> \
--key '{"ad_group":{"S":"bigdata"}}' \
--region <Table Region Here>
```

Comment: Yes, also it is not fetching the records based on that key. Why is it so?

Comment: What is your partition key and sort key for your table?

Comment: ad_group is the partition key

Comment: And there is no sort key? And what is the response now that you removed `Items`?

Comment: I am checking it rn.

Comment: This gives me a blank result. I am not sure why. No error is thrown. The response is empty. I just tested.

Comment: An empty result means that no item with that key exists in the table.

Comment: If I query from local I get the results

Comment: Add a try/except block, and extra logging. With the information you've provided theres not much I can help you with.

Comment: Yeah it was my mistake. Figured out and fixed. Thanks alot for the help :)